# Keyboard animation is delayed

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to move a scrollview content when keyboard shows up and hide. I am doing the basic functionality.
But keyboard is visible first and the moving up animation is delayed, and after updating to ios 11 it has more delay.

Code :

```
viewDidLoad(){
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {


        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
                self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = 0.0
            } else {
                self.keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint?.constant = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                           delay: TimeInterval(0),
                           options: animationCurve,
                           animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

`keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint` is scrollview's bottom constraint.

What am i doing wrong ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` key for keyboard animation. For better implementation, you can check out this blog http://eng.moldedbits.com/technical/ios/2017/08/28/typed-notification-ios.html

Comment: @Aks I am using UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame. Is it not okay ?

Comment: `WillChange` is posted before the frame change, Check this apple documentation for different notification for keyboard:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow

Comment: Just  suggesting you there are some libraries that automatically manage scrollview when your keyboard and you don't need to do anything just write one line code or change scrollView class. look at https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager and https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @Aks If i use willChange then its looking more delayed.

Comment: @iPatel Thanks and i tried IQKeyboardManager but after integrating unity its not working.

Comment: @sharadchauhan In your code above, you were already using `WillChange`. I suggested you to use `DidChnage`,  and see if you are still experiencing the delay.

Comment: @Aks Sorry, I meant didChange has more delay.

Comment: @sharadchauhan I use the code I mentioned in the blog in my production apps, and haven't faced any problem. You can give that a try. You can use `UIKeyboardWillShow` or `UIKeyboardDidShow` notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you try to this give scrollview's height and calculate with main view height - keyboard height and keyboardchangeframe will working delay, if you wanna catch keyboard open and hide you should add those to on viewdidload:

global: var keyboardHeight:CGFloat?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

and when load calculate scrollview height

```
self.scrollviewHeight.constant = self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight - self.textView.frame.height
```

you can calculate like this with UIView.animation